Uniqueness in Click Data View?
The click data view unlike others seems to struggle with uniqueness.
Job ID
List ID
Batch ID
Subscriber Key
Event Date UTC in Millisecond
LinkName

I thought these 5 fields from the _Click data view would produce unique rows but they do not, swapping LinkName for LinkContent doesn't either.
The challenges I'm seeing; duplicate, most likely machine opens are occurring within 1-20 seconds of each other, so it's hard to mark these as duplicates based on the click event time.
The other challenge is that for the ones that do have the exact same timestamp, they may or may not be the IsUnique click.
Has anyone been able to solve for this to some degree, what primary/composite keys are you using to identify each click event and how are you de-duplicating your results for engagement accuracy?

This is a pattern in a couple of Data Views. Root cause, I don't know.
Workaround:

Pull the Data View into a table that has all exact same fields and NO primary key. (That way you can also visually inspect this and take informed decisions)

On this table, I would then run a deduplication using ROW_NUMBER () OVER (Partition BY [your fields])... and decide that for exact duplicates, you just keep one.


For whatever "actual" reason these duplicates exist, you can probably safely say you don't need two exact same lines and just scrap them.
E.g. below, we use your listed fields (which sound plausible) to deduplicate, decide for the "newest" of the duplicates (whatever that means if milliseconds are the same) and omit doubles.
SELECT a.[all fields here]
FROM (
  SELECT [all fields here], ROW_NUMBER() OVER(Partition by
 JobID
 ,ListID
 ,BatchID
 ,SubscriberKey
 ,EventDate
 ,LinkName ORDER BY EventDate DESC) AS Row_Number   
  FROM [your copy of the data view]) a
WHERE a.Row_Number = 1

Follow up processes based on that result will simply don't work with the dupes any more.

The Click Data view, like the Open one, works like a "log table", meaning - SFMC just writes event logs there, without applying any logic.
You'll find duplicated records where every single field is duplicated, which is a bit annoying. Here's an article we wrote in DESelect about considerations when working with Data Views
Depending on the use case, I'd suggest setting primary keys to remove useless duplicates:

For link clicks: set SubKey, EventDate, JobId, URL as PKs.
For unique contact clicks: SubKey, JobId


You need to [edit] your answer to disclose your affiliation to that link you included. Otherwise, it is spam according to site policy.

Thank you @DerekF, I didn't know that! I included that we wrote it in DESelect so it's clear that I'm related to DESelect - is that enough? I think it's a valid article though, so no spam :)
